# Identifying structures from anterior end of dissected prawn

Tags: zoology, anatomy, dissection, species-identification

**Note: This image might be disturbing.**

I want to know what the red and the black structures (directly posterior to the red structure) are. I guess it's the heart.

[image]

Comment: are you sure about the antero-posterior axis in this picture ?
BTW, The image is not that disturbing but i think it is not a very good dissection :P

Answer (score 1):

I guess you got your antero-posterior axis wrong. If I am correct then anterior is right and posterior is left in your image. In that case the black structure should be the cerebral ganglion and the red should be the heart. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Aren't eyes of a prawn located at the anterior end ? If so, the red is towards the anterior end and the black towards the posterior. (I am not talking about the two black structures ie eyes. I am taking about the "black" to the left of the heart in the *picture* which would be posterior to the heart in prawns.

Comment: eyes are in the anterior but i cant see the eyes in your picture

Comment: see [this picture](http://www.mdfrc.org.au/bugguide/diagrams/DecapodaDorsal.jpg). this is another species of shrimp but you can clearly see eyes anterior to the cerebral ganglion. also it seems that you have dissected on the ventral surface; eyes are present on the dorsal surface.

Comment: I have dissected the dorsal surface and the 2 black structures are definitely eyes.

Comment: No.. The two dark things in the right of this pictures are the eyes/

Comment: Sorry for the bad dissection + bad orientation of the photo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14188/discussion-between-wysiwyg-and-biogirl)